# React modal rendering

Tags: reactjs

I've been created a modal that shows on the home page. Modal shows only when U enters the site from a mobile device. It is working well, but I want to have this render only the first time when the site is rendered. Now, whenever I came to the home page it shows.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the modal on the highest parent of the site component tree hierarchy (for example in  component) and then use the useEffect hook to make it show up only on the first render of the component like so: 
 `useEffect(() => { ....your logic here that triggers modal open } , []);`

Edit:
I see that you mentioned you are only using the state, so if the initialState if on the required state of modal open, then it will be enough to   just lift that state up to parent component of the higher component.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you render some other component it flushes its previous state at component level, There are 2 ways to do that, either you have to use state manager like redux or react's context api and store the state on root level. And if you do not want to show the page even after user closes the browser then consider using local storage.
some references:

1. [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
2. [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)
3. [Local Storage](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/localstorage-in-reactjs)